# C# Linq Query Issue

Tags: c#, linq

Hello I am trying to retrieve a specific department by ID.

This is my code

```
public void GetDeptId(int _DeptID)
{
var dept = dbContext.tblDepartments
    .Select(d => new Department
    {
        DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID,
        DepartmentName = d.DepartmentName
    }).Where(d => d.DepartmentID == _DeptID);
}
```

How do I filter the resultset based on _DeptID?? This is returning no records even though the record exists.

Comment: Is your return type supposed to be void in this example? When you debug and do dept.ToList() what do you get?

Comment: `d => new Department
    {
        DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID,` Where does `e` come from? Also I suggest filtering before getting everything so: `dbContext.tblDepartments.Where( /* filter */ ).Select( /* make object */ );`

Comment: Apart from the void return, does your code compile? What is variable e? Advise: if you use proper identifiers in your lambda expressions, you wouldn't refer to the incorrect parameter by accident: `.Where(department => deparement.DepartmentId == _departmentId)`

Comment: Does the record is retrieved without where section? Also try adding `.ToList()`. Entity framework works as lazy. So, the query may be even working just fine.

Comment: try `dbContext.tblDepartments.Where(c => c.DepartmentID == _DeptID).Select(d=> new Department{DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID,DepartmentName =d.DepartmentName}).ToList();`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Edited my post.

Comment: @Aarif that worked. Thank you.

Comment: @JackSmith glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
  public ICollection<Department> GetDeptId(int _DeptID)
{
var dept = dbContext.tblDepartments
    .Select(d => new Department
    {
        DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID,
        DepartmentName = e.DepartmentName
    }).Where(c => c.DepartmentID == _DeptID).ToList();
 return dept;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the Select clause?
If you just need to retrieve one department, you could do something like this:

```
public void GetDeptId(int _DeptID)
{
    var depts = dbContext.tblDepartments
                        .Where(d => d.DepartmentID == _DeptID);
}
```

Or, if it's just one, which would make sense it is:

```
public void GetDeptId(int _DeptID)
{
    var dept = dbContext.tblDepartments
                        .First(d => d.DepartmentID == _DeptID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
var dept = dbContext.tblDepartments.Where(d => d.DepartmentID == _DeptID)
    .Select(d => new Department
    {
        DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID,
        DepartmentName = d.DepartmentName
    });
}
```